# Redshift Cross join ignoring where clause

Tags: amazon-redshift, cross-join

I have the following query:

```
WITH MY_CTE as
(
select
....
.....
    )
SELECT
MY_CTE.*
,tt.currency as most_used_currency
from MY_CTE
cross join 
     (select t.currency
      from My_CTE t
      group by t.currency
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
     ) tt 
where MY_CTE.currency = 'EUR'
```

but the cross join is ignoring my where clause.
How can I enforce that it processes the where clause before working on the cross join please?

Sample data returned:

[image: ![enter image description here]

This is obviously wrong because I said do not include currency SEK, and yet it is saying its the most popular currency.
I cannot put the where clause inside of the cross join because I will be using this in tableau and need the users to be able to filter on certain criteria, e.g. currency.

The most popular currency should be EUR if the MY_CTE is filtered to show only EUR currency

Comment: Maybe problem is that comparison in SQL is performed by single =, not double ==
Also notice which column you are looking at: MY_CTE.currency or tt.currency. tt.currency values will not be affected by your filter.

Comment: is there any way i can filter on the cross join?

Comment: Cross join is the only join which doesn't require any conditions. There is no such thing as filter on join. When you use join you set join conditions `on .....` . Filter is what you define in `WHERE ...` part of SQL. Maybe it would be easier to understand if you could provide data sample and expected result.

Comment: edited to show the results I am getting

Answer (score 1):

WHERE condition in this case has nothing to do with cross join, it just filters rows after join is already performed. If you need to report only single currency there are simplest two options where to add currency filter (added as comments in SQL):

1) Option 1 - add filter already in CTE statement

2) Option 2 - add filter at the end (as already done) and within tt part.

```
WITH MY_CTE as
(
select
....
.....
/* OPTION 1*/
    )
SELECT
MY_CTE.*
,tt.currency as most_used_currency
from MY_CTE
cross join 
     (select t.currency
      from My_CTE t
     /* OPTION 2 first place*/
      group by t.currency
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
     ) tt 
where MY_CTE.currency = 'EUR' /* OPTION 2a second place*/
```

Comment: the problem is that I need to use this in tableau and users should be able to filter on currency and other things. so it needs to be outside (where it currently is)

Comment: Unless there is some option to set filters using some variables in tableau, there is technically no option to do it as just filter at the end of SQL statement. In postgresql (starting from 9.5) there is aggregate function `mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sort_expression)` but such functionality isn't available in Redshift. Also there is no option to create aggregate user defined functions in Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

The alias tt will return the most popular currency overall, which is SEK. If you want to filter for separate currencies, you'll need to put them in the inner query as well as the outer one. However, if that isn't an option, you'll want to return all currencies with their popularity, and filter on the most popular one you allow.

```
....
....
SELECT
LAST_VALUE(MY_CTE.customer_id) 
           OVER (partition by customer_id 
           ORDER BY tt.popularity
      rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) 
.... /* rest of your columns */
, LAST_VALUE(tt.currency) 
           OVER (partition by customer_id 
           ORDER BY tt.popularity
      rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) 
from MY_CTE
cross join 
 (select t.currency,
         count(*) popularity
      from My_CTE t
      group by t.currency
      order by count(*) desc
      /* removed limit 1 */
     ) tt 
where MY_CTE.currency = 'EUR' 
  AND tt.currency IN ('EUR') /* Added tt.currency filter */
```

Comment: Reason why there is most popular section of currencies, is that it can be ran also without currency filter. And without filter it would produce cartesian product which is not desired.